# Update query for Mongo document in Redash

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, redash

I am trying to look for a query to update a record in Mongo document using Redash. I came up with the following query but it does not work. Can anyone please help? What I know about Redash is that it uses Pymongo.

```
{
  "collection": "Application",
    "update": [{
      "$match": {
        "ID": "2001"
      },
      "$set": {
        "ID": "2020"
      }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used Redash, but in pymongo the construct would be:

```
db = MongoClient()['mydatabase'] # Set the database connection
db.Application.update_one({"ID": "2001"}, {"$set": {"ID": "2020"}}) # Perform the update
```